# Good webmail service provider

Tags: email, webmail

Short background:
We are a small webhosting company serving NGOs. We have over 2000 mailboxes on 500 domains. Our biggest problem is the crappy Horde webmail we provide to our customers today. Our server provider is married with Parallels PLESK and PBA suites, and cannot integrate another webmail than Horde to their offering.

So we want to provide a better mailservice (especially webmail and mobile mail).
Now, we love gmail and Google Apps, but as far as I can decipher online there is no way to manage this many domains and accounts centraliced through their admin panels, or is there? Google is not ansvering my questions on this, I guess theyre not intesrested in dealing with small companies like ours.

**What we need is:**

- A mail service that has good webmail and preferably a decent mobile interface
- Price up to 20€/account/year (up to 50€/account/year with shared calendars and docs), min space 1Gb/account
- Control panel with 3 user levels

  - us (reseller, global admin): to manage all 500 domains and their 2000 accounts
  - domain admin: ability to administrate all the mailboxes (accounts) in their domain
  - user panel: for the mail user to manage passwords, autoresponders...
- API: We have hosting plans with DNS templates in our PBA environment. These automatically point the MX-records to the mailprovider (the rest to our webservers, such as www, ftp and so on), so there must be an easy way to start new domains at the mailprovider, preferably by a script on our server.

I guess the initial migration to the new mailprovider is going to be a pain in the behind. We do get our current account data exported as XML and CSV, but what about the other end, any services with migration tools?

Comment: FWIW [Webapps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) might also be a valuable place to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [Atmail](http://www.atmail.com/) might be a good solution for you.

A suitable configuration might be:

- Atmail Server
- Hosted Cloud
- ISP license

Works out to be USD0.50/month for 3GB storage, which is way under your EUR20/year budget.

You can work out your own configuration here:

- http://www.atmail.com/store/